# How to sample in Bayesian inference model?

Tags: bayesian, sampling, inference, rejection-sampling

I have the following problem to model in R.

If we have $X_1, ..., X_n \sim N(\theta,1)$ and want to estimate $\theta$, we assume $\theta$ has a prior distribution, and the Bayes estimate of $\theta$ is the mean of

$$\pi(\theta | x_1, ..., x_n) \propto \frac{1}{\pi(1+\theta^2)}\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-(x_i - \theta)^2/2}$$.

Assume we have some $n$ samples, I am trying to use rejection sampling for this problem. Normally, if I have some distribution $p(x)$ (or $l(x)$ such that $p(x) \propto l(x)$) that I want to sample from, I find another distribution $g(x)$ and constant $c$ such that $p(x) \leq cg(x)$ (or, alternatively, $l(x) \leq cg(x)$), but in this case I have trouble finding what my distribution $p(x)$ is. Is it the whole thing after the $\propto$ symbol? If so, how do I work this out since I have an unknown distribution $\pi$? Or is it that the problem is abusing notation and the $\pi$ symbols to the right of $\propto$ are the constant $\pi$?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You only have one symbol $\pi$ and both times it occurs it is the constant $\pi$. Since it is on the right-hand side of the proportionality sign, you can just drop both of them.

Comment: I realized too late! Thank you! I was breaking my head over it because on the left-hand side it is the distribution and on the right hand side it is just the constant $\pi$.